# How can I pass the number of rows on the page into a column definition with react table v7?

Tags: javascript, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a table built on react table v7 with pagination enabled. I'd like to display the indeterminate icon in my header (select all) checkbox when only some of the rows on a page are selected.

[image]

In order to achieve this, I can compare the number of selected rows to the number of rows on the page. Is there a way to pass the number of rows on the page into the react table column header definition?

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my column header definition for the header checkbox cell. Irrelevant to the question, but to be complete with my description here, the [Checkbox](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/) component is from the Material UI library.

```
        Header: (cell) => {
            return (
                <Checkbox
                    color="default"
                    onClick={(e) => handleAllCheckbox(e, cell?.filteredRows)}
                    checked={checked.allLanes}
                    indeterminate={
                        checked.selectedLane.length > 0 &&
                        checked.selectedLane.length !== rowsOnPage
                    }
                />
            );
        },
```